# PHP domdocument if statement for when img tag has no alt attribute or if alt attribute is empty?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using this code to get the alt attribute from img tags using domdocument. If a page has images without an alt attribute or if the alt attribute is empty it doesn't recognize that. I need some help writing the conditions to check for empty alt attributes as well as none at all. Thanks

```
$name =  trim($words->nodeName);
    if($name == 'img' ) 
        {
            $alt= $words->getAttribute('alt');
            if(!empty($alt)) 
        {
    $this->matchedAnchors[$this->count]['alt']     =  trim($words->getAttribute('alt'));
```

Comment: So are you getting an error? Also, try using `if (isset($alt) && !empty($alt))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath for that:

```
//img[normalize-space(@alt) != '']
```

Example:

```php
$xml = <<< XML
<ul>
    <li><img alt="foo"/></li>
    <li><img alt="   "/></li>
    <li><img alt=""/></li>
    <li><img /></li>
</ul>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xp->query('//img[normalize-space(@alt) != ""]') as $img) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($img);
}
```

will only print

```
<img alt="foo"/>
```

[Demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/lQePpsex)

Comment: I actually do need to find img alts which are empty as well as ones with data, I ended up adding an else statement after the  if(!empty($alt)) so if alt was found empty to handle it as needed. Thank you though

Comment: @Anagio in that case you can simply query for `//img[@alt]`

Comment: Thanks, do you know if XPath has any performance differences than domdocument?

Comment: @Anagio DOMXPath and DOMDocument are both part of the DOM extension and use libxml underneath. You should not worry about performance here. When in doubt, benchmark.